# DataAnnotations driving client side validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get what I think is a simple example of using DataAnnotations on a model to drive the client side validation as well.

Here is my model...

```
 public class Person
 {
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name Required")]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name Required")]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
```

Here is my controller...

```
 public class FriendsController : Controller
 {
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
   Person newFriend = new Person();
   return View(newFriend);
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Create(Person friendToCreate)
  {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
    // todo -- do something here
    return Redirect("/");
   }

   // Invalid - redisplay form with errors
   return View(friendToCreate);
  }
 }
```

and here is my view...

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.Person
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Create</h2>
    @{Html.EnableClientValidation();}
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    { 
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)
            </p>
            <p>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName)
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

The server side validation works just fine and the validation error messages appear as expected.  However, I am not getting the client side validation to work.  Is there something obvious that I am missing to make the client side validation appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enabled Client side Validation on your web.config file?

You can do it directly on the web.config file adding a couple of flags inside the appSetting section

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

or you can do it using pure c# code

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

I recommend you read Brad Wilson's article [Unobtrusive Client Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  And I just read Brad's article, thanks for the link.  He described the exact problem I was having.

Turns out if I remove the MS scripts from above and instead include jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, then the client side validation works just fine!  It seems for MVC3 the MS specific stuff is giving way to the JSON implementation.  Glad to see MS is going this direction rather than try to eat the whole apple by themselves.