# MVC Model require true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Is there a way through data annotations to require that a boolean property be set to true?

```
public class MyAwesomeObj{
    public bool ThisMustBeTrue{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the use case of this? Couldn't you just let the property be read-only and return true all the time?

Comment: It's pretty much to say... hey buddy you forgot to check the I agree... which should make the model invalid.

Comment: I think this is something you'd want to handle client-side.

Comment: @PsychoCoder: It should be handled on both sides... not just client side.  I was just looking to see if it could be handled by adding a simple data annotation.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could create your own validator:

```
public class IsTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    #region Overrides of ValidationAttribute

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified value of the object is valid. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the specified value is valid; otherwise, false. 
    /// </returns>
    /// <param name="value">The value of the specified validation object on which the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute"/> is declared.
    ///                 </param>
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");

        return (bool) value;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: I'd consider enhancing this with a client side implementation - rather than using the remote validation referred to in other answers, use the unobtrusive spelt out here: http://www.jacopretorius.net/2011/01/client-side-validation-in-mvc-3.html

Comment: This is a good (and tested) quick solution for us. We can do without the client side validation in @dazbradbury's solution (also a good one) because we only need this on a lone checkbox on the past page of a survey.

Comment: `return (bool) value == true;` this is a redundant comparison

Answer (score 132):

I would create a validator for both Server AND Client side. Using MVC and unobtrusive form validation, this can be achieved simply by doing the following:

Firstly, create a class in your project to perform the server side validation like so:

```
public class EnforceTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");
        return (bool)value == true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return "The " + name + " field must be checked in order to continue.";
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage) ? FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName) : ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "enforcetrue"
        };
    }
}
```

Following this, annotate the appropriate property in your model:

```
[EnforceTrue(ErrorMessage=@"Error Message")]
public bool ThisMustBeTrue{ get; set; }
```

And Finally, enable client side validation by adding the following script to your View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("enforcetrue", function (value, element, param) {
        return element.checked;
    });
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("enforcetrue");
</script>
```

Note: We already created a method `GetClientValidationRules` which pushes our annotation to the view from our model.

If using resource files to supply the error message for internationalization, remove the `FormatErrorMessage` call (or just call the base) and tweak the `GetClientValidationRules` method like so:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    string errorMessage = String.Empty;
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessage))
    {
        // Check if they supplied an error message resource
        if(ErrorMessageResourceType != null && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ErrorMessageResourceName))
        {
            var resMan = new ResourceManager(ErrorMessageResourceType.FullName, ErrorMessageResourceType.Assembly);
            errorMessage = resMan.GetString(ErrorMessageResourceName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage = ErrorMessage;
    }

    yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage,
        ValidationType = "enforcetrue"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works great! It works better with the override  FormatErrorMessage method removed - that way localisation of error messages from Resource files works. My usage: [EnforceTrue(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(ValidationMessages), ErrorMessageResourceName = "TermsAndConditionsRequired")]

Comment: I can't get the client side validation to work and can't seem to tell what I'm doing wrong. Where exactly should I put the javacsript? In the head tag? Next to the controller?

Comment: Great solution showing the power of custom validation attributes! Though I recommend putting the script in a globally referenced js file, not the view(s), for reuse. Also, best to handle all ways the message strings could be added: default if none provided, or the message string, or from a resource file.

Comment: How would I do this without yield VB.net 2012 is not recognizing that key word and it is driving me crazy as I just wanted to do one simple thing and now I am down a rabbit hole.

Comment: Great solution, thanks for posting. For those who can't get the client side valdation to work: You have to extend jQuery validation before the controls that it will validate have been loaded, so put the script in the head, and not in the window.onload / $(document).ready() event.

Answer (score 98):

I know this is an older post but wanted to share a simple server side way to do this. You create a public property set to true and compare your bool to that property. If your bool is not checked (by default false) the form will not validate.

```
public bool isTrue
{ get { return true; } }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "I agree to the terms and conditions")]
[Compare("isTrue", ErrorMessage = "Please agree to Terms and Conditions")]
public bool AgreeTerms { get; set; }
```

Razor code

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.AgreeTerms, new { id = "AgreeTerms", @checked = "checked" })
<label asp-for="AgreeTerms" class="control-label"></label>
<a target="_blank" href="/Terms">Read</a>
<br />
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgreeTerms, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.isTrue)
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity. FYI: I had to make the 'isTrue' property public for this to work.

Comment: Compare  is not there for me in MVC4

Comment: Super solution great solution

Comment: And if you add a hidden for the "isTrue" property, you get client side validation

Comment: Annoying this great looking solution did not work for me. Tested on Mvc 5.2.3.

Comment: @Harvey I am also on 5.2.3 but it works perfect for me

Comment: @billoreid Thanks for elaborating and making the client validation easy for me to figure out too.

Comment: @Harvey Didn't work for me either, but I just posted a simpler version that did work for me. Not sure why.

Comment: Not working for me because it ends up trying to compare `"true"` to `"True"` where the first is the checkbox value the latter is the hidden field value (which is the booling `ToString()` result)

Comment: Is the `[Required]` attribute not redundant here given that a bool will never be `null`?

Answer (score 26):

I tried several solutions but none of them worked completely for me to get both client and server side validation. So what I did in my MVC 5 application to get it to work:

**In your ViewModel (for server side validation):**

```
public bool IsTrue => true;

[Required]
[Display(Name = "I agree to the terms and conditions")]
[Compare(nameof(IsTrue), ErrorMessage = "Please agree to Terms and Conditions")]
public bool HasAcceptedTermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

**In your Razor page (for client side validation):**

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTermsAndConditions)
   @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTermsAndConditions)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTermsAndConditions)

   @Html.Hidden(nameof(Model.IsTrue), "true")
</div>
```

Comment: Charming solution!

Comment: Take care of the value for the hidden field ("true")!

Answer (score 10):

I would just like to direct people to the following Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JbPh0X

The user added
`[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "You gotta tick the box!")]` to their boolean property which causes server side validation to work.

In order to also have the client side validation working, they added the following script:

```
// extend jquery range validator to work for required checkboxes
var defaultRangeValidator = $.validator.methods.range;
$.validator.methods.range = function(value, element, param) {
    if(element.type === 'checkbox') {
        // if it's a checkbox return true if it is checked
        return element.checked;
    } else {
        // otherwise run the default validation function
        return defaultRangeValidator.call(this, value, element, param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just check to see whether its string representation is equal to `True`:

```
[RegularExpression("True")]
public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

Comment: @JeradRose It's validated just fine on the server. Are you referring to client-side validation?

Comment: Confirmed, this works server side but not client side

Comment: I thought the server side validation may have a type mismatch exception trying to compare a bool to a string.

Comment: `RegularExpressionAttribute` internally uses `Convert.ToString` to get the string representation of the property's value (which is delivered to it as an `object`).

Comment: I think this answer is simpler than @fields-cage  +1 from me

Answer (score 5):

You could either create your own attribute or use the [CustomValidationAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(v=VS.95).aspx).

This is how you would use the CustomValidationAttribute:

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(BoolValidation), "ValidateBool")]
```

where BoolValidation is defined as:

```
public class BoolValidation
{
  public static ValidationResult ValidateBool(bool boolToBeTrue)
  {
    if (boolToBeTrue)
    {
      return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    else
    {
      return new ValidationResult(
          "Bool must be true.");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

`[Required]` attribute stands for requiring *any* value - it can be either true or false. You'd have to use another validation for that.

Answer (score 4):

Following up on the post by ta.speot.is and the comment from Jerad Rose:

The given post will not work client-side with unobtrusive validation. 
This should work in both camps (client & server):

```
[RegularExpression("(True|true)")]
public bool TermsAndConditions { get; set; }
```

Comment: Don't know if this is a newer version issue, but it's not working for me with jquery.validate 1.19.2 and jquery.validate.unobtrusive 3.2.11. The problem seems to be the `regex` method unobtrusive defines first checks whether the checkbox is optional before validating the regex, which makes sense, except that jquery.validate appears to consider any unchecked checkbox to be optional. tl;dr It only runs the regex on checked checkboxes. We can add a shim for the `regex` `validator` method or just create a custom validator.

Answer (score 3):

For **ASP.NET Core MVC** here is client and server validation, based on dazbradbury's solution

```
public class EnforceTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        if (value.GetType() != typeof(bool)) throw new InvalidOperationException("can only be used on boolean properties.");
        return (bool)value;
    }

    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val", "true");
        var errorMessage = ErrorMessage ?? 
            $"The value for field {context.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()} must be true.";
        MergeAttribute(context.Attributes, "data-val-enforcetrue", errorMessage);
    }

    private void MergeAttribute(IDictionary<string, string> attributes,
        string key,
        string value)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return;
        }
        attributes.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

And then on the client:

```
$.validator.addMethod("enforcetrue", function (value, element, param) {
    return element.checked;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("enforcetrue");
```

Then usage is:

```
[EnforceTrue(ErrorMessage = "Please tick the checkbox")]
public bool IsAccepted { get; set; }
```

Comment: When use this solution, consider [this](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/7894). Put the javascript code outside any "jquery `$document.ready()`/`$(function() { });`".

Comment: Another tip, NOT put `required` attribute on HTML input, like: `<input asp-for="..." class="..." id="..." type="checkbox" required/>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way through DataAnnotations, but this is easily done in your controller.

```
public ActionResult Add(Domain.Something model)
{

    if (!model.MyCheckBox)
        ModelState.AddModelError("MyCheckBox", "You forgot to click accept");

    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //'# do your stuff
    }

}
```

The only other option would be to build a custom validator for the server side and a [remote validator](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx) for the client side (remote validation is only available in MVC3+)

Comment: Kinda already new how to check the boolean flag already.... wanted to know if there was a dataannotation for it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the [appropriate items set up in the web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485820/dataannotations-driving-client-side-validation-issue)?

That could cause the validation not to work.

You can also try to create a custom validation attribute (since `[Required]` only cares whether or not it exists, and you care about the value):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed public class RequiredTrueAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    // Internal field to hold the mask value.
    readonly bool accepted;

    public bool Accepted
    {
        get { return accepted; }
    }

    public RequiredTrueAttribute(bool accepted)
    {
        this.accepted = accepted;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        bool isAccepted = (bool)value;
        return (isAccepted == true);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
          ErrorMessageString, name, this.Accepted);
    }
}
```

Then, usage:

```
[RequiredTrue(ErrorMessage="{0} requires acceptance to continue.")]
public bool Agreement {get; set;}
```

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me. Nothing else did. Mvc 5:

**Model**

```
public string True
{
  get
  {
    return "true";
  }
}

[Required]
[Compare("True", ErrorMessage = "Please agree to the Acknowlegement")]
public bool Acknowlegement { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.True)
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Acknowlegement, new { htmlAttributes = Model.Attributes })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Acknowlegement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use fields.cage's answer and it didn't quite work for me, but something simpler did, and I'm not sure exactly why (different Razor version, maybe?), but all I had to do was this:

```
[Required]
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Agreement required.")]
[Display(Name = "By clicking here, I agree that my firstborn child will etc etc...")]
public bool Agreement1Checked { get; set; }
```

And in the .cshtml file:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Agreement1Checked)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Agreement1Checked)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Agreement1Checked)
```

Comment: This doesn't work client-side for me. For some reason the parameter passed to the jquery.validate rule method is `[NaN, NaN]` where it should be `[true, true]`

Comment: @xr280xr Even when the user has checked the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to handle this is just check in your controller if the box is true otherwise just add an error to your model and have it redisplay your view.

As previously stated all [Required] does is make sure there is a value and in your case if not checked you still get false.

Answer (score -1):

```
/// <summary> 
///  Summary : -CheckBox for or input type check required validation is not working the root cause and solution as follows
///
///  Problem :
///  The key to this problem lies in interpretation of jQuery validation 'required' rule. I digged a little and find a specific code inside a jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js file:
///  adapters.add("required", function (options) {
///  if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() !== "INPUT" || options.element.type.toUpperCase() !== "CHECKBOX") {
///    setValidationValues(options, "required", true);
///    }
///   });
///   
///  Fix: (Jquery script fix at page level added in to check box required area)
///  jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("brequired", function (options) {
///   if (options.element.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT" && options.element.type.toUpperCase() == "CHECKBOX") {
///              options.rules["required"] = true;
///   if (options.message) {
///                   options.messages["required"] = options.message;
///                       }
///  Fix : (C# Code for MVC validation)
///  You can see it inherits from common RequiredAttribute. Moreover it implements IClientValidateable. This is to make assure that rule will be propagated to client side (jQuery validation) as well.
///  
///  Annotation example :
///   [BooleanRequired]
///   public bool iAgree { get; set' }
/// </summary>


public class BooleanRequired : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{

    public BooleanRequired()
    {
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (bool)value == true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new ModelClientValidationRule[] { new ModelClientValidationRule() { ValidationType = "brequired", ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage } };
    }
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: It works Check this link with reason why it fails on validation-http://itmeze.com/2010/12/06/checkbox-has-to-be-checked-with-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-and-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Today it works. Can you be sure it will stay working in 5, 10 years later? These Q&A DB is created for future users too

Answer (score -1):

Check out Foolproof validation [here](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/). You can download/install it via Nuget.

It's a great little library for this kind of thing.

Comment: Ehhhh... Default validation attributes work pretty well though.

Comment: Ehhhh... yeah but so does Foolproof?