# MVC [Required] attribute not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I'm new to MVC and trying to do a simple application form with a check box to accept the terms.
I cant understand why my error message isnt showing.
 This is my .cshtml

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="validation-container">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)
   </div>
    <div class="label-container">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)</div>
    <div class="form-control">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)</div>
</div>
```

my ViewModel

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please indicate you have read the statements above before sending your request")]
    [Display (Name = "Please tick to show you accept all the above statements")]
        public bool HasAcceptedTerms
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult AppForm(AppFormViewModel App)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }

        return View(App);
    }
```

When I click the button, the page refreshes with no changes. While debugging, the `Model.State` is `false`, so I really cant understand why nothing is happening. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a value type, your `bool` has a default value of `false` - this *is* a value and therefore does not get recognised as "missing".  You will need to validate that the value is `true`, rather than being required.

You could look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730183/mvc-model-require-true) question for a way to achieve this.

Comment: Oh ok I didnt see it like that. Is that why the Model.State was showing as false, because the checkbox was not checked therefor is false?

Comment: @user6950100 yes that's about right, although even if there was no form control to bind with it would still come through as false.  Basically, using `RequiredAttribute` won't give you what you need.