# Display Template for a checkbox in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frontend

I'm wanting a checkbox in my MVC project for an application form where you have to check the box at the end to say you agree to the terms and conditions. I am using

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="validation-container">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)
   </div>
    <div class="label-container">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)</div>
    <div class="form-control">@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HasAcceptedTerms)</div>
</div>
```

I am then using the property

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must indicate you have read the statements above before continuing")]
    [Display (Name = "Please tick to show you accept all the above statements")]
public bool? HasAcceptedTerms
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

However, this is now giving me a dropdown with three values: `not set`, `true`, false`.

How can I get this back to a checkbox?

By the way, it has to be a nullable bool otherwise the validation doesn't work because by default the checkbox will be unchecked meaning false which IS a value.

I want to be able to see a checkbox and the validation will prevent the person from continuing on the server side if the checkbox is not checked.

I also read you can do this by adding another DisplayTemplate but not sure if this would apply to me. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

A nullable `bool` has 3 states (`true`, `false` and `null`), but a check nox has only 2 states (on/off which translates to `true` and `false`) which is why a dropownlist is generated. You cannot use a checkbox for a nullable `bool`.

Create a custom validation attribute that implements `IClientValidatable` to validate that the value must be `true` and apply it to a `public bool HasAcceptedTerms { get; set; }` property (not nullable). Refer dazbradbury's answer to [MVC Model require true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730183/mvc-model-require-true) for an example.